# Триггеры mysql (обновить поле активной таблицы)

Tags: mysql, триггер, mysql-workbench

Всем привет! Ребят, подскажите, как правильно создать триггер который будет обновлять поле таблицы table1 при событии update этой же самой table1? Вот как я делаю:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER 
       TRIGGER `cinema2`.`user_AFTER_UPDATE` 
       AFTER UPDATE 
       ON `user` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE user SET `password` = '' WHERE id = old.id;
END
```

в итоге получаю

`#1442 - Can't update table 'user' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Comment: используйте before update

Comment: Спасибо, все работает

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался :)
Проблема была в том, что значения нужно обновлять ДО события UPDATE, а не после.

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER 
       TRIGGER `cinema2`.`user_BEFORE_UPDATE` 
       BEFORE UPDATE 
       ON `user` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`password` = md5(NEW.`password`);
END
```

Comment: Да, именно так, просто присваиванием полю в NEW. И ключевое тут не только то, что это надо делать ДО, но и то, что использовать операцию update на ту же таблицу нельзя (хотя бы по той причине, что если бы это было можно, то триггер был запустился второй раз и в итоге зациклился)